# Understand Data Factory Data Flow REST source behaviour when the response is json array

Tags: rest, azure-data-factory

I’m trying to understand how the REST source works in a data factory Data Flow. I will start with a simple case.
This is a sample response of my API (https://reqres.in/api/users):

```
{
    "page": 2,
    "per_page": 6,
    "total": 12,
    "total_pages": 2,
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 7,
            "email": "michael.lawson@reqres.in",
            "first_name": "Michael",
            "last_name": "Lawson",
            "avatar": "https://reqres.in/img/faces/7-image.jpg"
        },
        {
            "id": 8,
            "email": "lindsay.ferguson@reqres.in",
            "first_name": "Lindsay",
            "last_name": "Ferguson",
            "avatar": "https://reqres.in/img/faces/8-image.jpg"
        },
    ],
    "support": {
        "url": "https://reqres.in/#support-heading",
        "text": "To keep ReqRes free, contributions towards server costs are appreciated!"
    }
}
```

As you can see, the response payload is a **Json Object** with a `data` array containing the actual data content.

I need to unroll the `data` field and save in a csv file using a Data Flow. That's pretty straightforward:

- Source Projection is defining a field named `data` of type `complex array` inside the `body` column:
  [image]
- Let's now unroll by `data` field and use an explicit mapping:
  [image]
- Just make data flow into the Sink with the auto-map feature:
  [image]

Now, let's change our source, with a slightly different response (https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts):

```
[
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "title": "sunt aut facere repellat",
    "body": "quia et suscipit suscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita"
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 2,
    "title": "qui est esse",
    "body": "est rerum tempore vitae"
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 3,
    "title": "ea molestias",
    "body": "et iusto sed quo"
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 4,
    "title": "eum et est occaecati",
    "body": "ullam et saepe reiciendis voluptatem adipisci"
  }
]
```

In this case, the response body is just a **Json Array**. This particular detail, makes it impossible to reach the same goal as before.

- The projection shows the `body` which is defined as a `complex object` **and not as a complex array as I would expect**.
  [image]
- In fact, unrolling data will be not allowed (the option is grayed out)
  [image]
- Also, trying to directly write the `body` field into a csv sink will result in a validation error:
  [image]

Eventually, i found a workaround where you should use the **Aggregate** task combined with the **collect()** function. But, it is just a lot of overhead.

I still think I'm missing something, but it seems that **Data Factory Data Flows** don't support Json Array object as a response payload from a REST source.

Comment: The `Flatten transformation` work with the **array values inside hierarchical structures**

Answer (score 1):

The `Flatten transformation` work with the **array values inside hierarchical structures** in your second example you have Araay value but it's not hierarchical structures.

To unfold this type of structure you can use derived column also.

[image]

Output:

[image]

**Update:**

If you don't want to map manually you can use column pattenrn to map the matching columns accordingly with below settings.

```
Each body mathch condition - true()
Hierarchy level - body
column name expression and columnexpression as - $$
```

[image]

Comment: This seems to be a solution. But is it possible reach the same result with no mapping at all, using name and byName parameters?

Comment: check updated answer.